# Freeradius radcrypt encryption in PHP

Tags: php, passwords, crypt, freeradius

I'm looking for a solution in PHP Similar to the output of radcrypt.

I've looked into mcrypt and can't seem to figure out which cipher and setting i should use.

Mcrypt wants a salt to add to the encryption but radcrypt doesn't seem to have a salt.

Anyone knows what the cipher and/or settings of radcrypt are?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need mcrypt for this.  These passwords as *hashed*, not encrypted.

The `radcrypt` script is [built from this bit of Perl](https://github.com/FreeRADIUS/freeradius-server/blob/master/scripts/cryptpasswd.in).  It relies on Perl's [built-in `crypt` function](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/crypt.html), which has semantics similar to [the standard `crypt` function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crypt_%28C%29).

PHP [also provides `crypt`](http://php.net/crypt).  Until 5.3, PHP used the same exact functionality, called in the same exact way, generating the same hashes.  Starting in 5.3, PHP's implementation became bundled with the language instead of relying on external libraries, allowing for additions and enhancements.

The `radcrypt` script *automatically* produces a salt, using two characters for DES and eight for MD5:

```
$salt = ($opt_md5 ? '$1$' : '');
for ($i = 0; $i < ($opt_md5 ? 8 : 2); $i++) {
    $salt .= $saltc[rand 64];
}
$salt .= '$' if ($opt_md5);
print crypt($ARGV[0], $salt), "\n";
```

DES crypt stores the hash as the first two characters.  For example, `crypt('password', 'aa')` produces `aajfMKNH1hTm2`.

MD5 crypt stores the hash as part of a `$` delimited section.  For example, `crypt('password', '$1$iamasalt$')` produces `$1$iamasalt$RSUhkOk5NVnvbM3BPw/g8/`.

Knowing this, you can now correctly create the expected password format using PHP, or *any* other language that supplies standard `crypt`.  `crypt` also knows how to extract the salt from the hashed string, so you can pass the already hashed password right back in order to verify the password:

```
$hash = '$1$iamasalt$RSUhkOk5NVnvbM3BPw/g8/';
$password = 'password';
if($hash == crypt($password, $hash)) {
    print "Passwords matched.\n";
}
```

Incidentally, that code is valid in both Perl and PHP.

Please be sure to read the Wikipedia article above, especially the sections concerning password security.  Neither the DES nor MD5 hashes are secure against brute-force attacks.  You should not use either of these methods unless you are required to by something that only supports these two hash types (like, I dunno, FreeRADIUS).

Comment: FreeRADIUS doesn't require this, it supports many other hashes.

Comment: This is one heck of a solution and should be used for everyone inserting encrypted passwords through PHP +a thousand. Thanks for the extremely helpful and detailed information. Worked for me!